# How to make a sprite correct path?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, blit

I am trying to create a small and very simple simulation that makes a meteor appear in the middle of the screen and move away... until the users presses a key. While the key is pressed, the path is corrected dynamically to a new path.

I tried two different method, first the KEYDOWN, and then the pygame.key.get_pressed() function, but in both cases, after I release the key, the image "Meteor" drops down again to its orginal path.

I was hoping one could indicate me what I am doing wrong.

Here my code so far:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from colors import *
import random


FPS = 30 
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()


pygame.init()

X_Display = 400
Y_Display = 400

DisplaySurf = pygame.display.set_mode((X_Display, Y_Display))
DisplaySurf.fill(Silver)
pygame.display.set_caption("Meteor")

X_Real_Max = X_Display/2
Y_Real_Max = Y_Display/2
X_Center = 0
Y_Center = 0

XMeteor = 40
YMeteor = 20
XCenterMeteor = 0
YCenterMeteor = 0
XPosMeteor = XCenterMeteor + (200 - (XMeteor/2))
YPosMeteor = YCenterMeteor + (200 - (YMeteor/2))

imgMeteor = pygame.image.load("Desktop\imgMeteor.png")

VisEffect = 1.05


while True:

    XMeteor *= VisEffect
    YMeteor *= VisEffect

    XCenterMeteor *= VisEffect
    YCenterMeteor *= VisEffect

    XPosMeteor = XCenterMeteor + (200 - (XMeteor/2))
    YPosMeteor = YCenterMeteor + (200 - (YMeteor/2))

    #Pressed  = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #if Pressed[pygame.K_w]:
        #YPosMeteor -= 10

    if XMeteor > 150:
        XMeteor = 40
        YMeteor = 20
        XCenterMeteor = random.randrange(-100, 100)
        YCenterMeteor = random.randrange(-100, 100)
        XPosMeteor = XCenterMeteor + (200 - (XMeteor/2))
        YPosMeteor = YCenterMeteor + (200 - (YMeteor/2))

    Meteor = pygame.transform.scale(imgMeteor, (int(XMeteor),int(YMeteor)))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        #if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #if event.key == K_w:
                #YPosMeteor -= 50
        #elif event.type == KEYUP:
            #YPosMeteor = YPosMeteor


    DisplaySurf.blit(Meteor, (XPosMeteor, YPosMeteor))
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
    DisplaySurf.fill(Silver)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the wrong variable.  `YPosMeteor` is clobbered every time through the loop, so when you change that variable there is no lasting effect.  You want to change either `YCenterMeteor` or `YMeteor`.

Comment: Oh! Right, that makes a lot more sense. Ill check it out!